# Fileupload with curl. Php

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, file-type

I use curl in my project. Version of the libcurl is 7.18.2. It's a bug (does't work filetype), more  - [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#97591). For fileupload I use this code:

```
if ( !empty($_POST) ){
     $post = $_POST;
 }

if ( !empty($_FILES) ){
   foreach ($_FILES as $param => $file) {
         if ( $file['tmp_name'] )
                $files[$param] = '@' . $file['tmp_name'] . ';filename=' . $file['name'] . ';type=' . $file['type'];
   }
}

$post = !empty($files) ? array_merge($post, $files) : $post;

// ...

if ( $curl = curl_init() ) {

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
  
  if ( !empty($post) ) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  }

  $content = curl_exec($curl);
  
  curl_close ($curl);
}
```

Please tell me, how I can send type of a file on a server? The libcurl upgrade is not possible.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can't you just use another post field for file type?

Comment: What did you mean? $_POST['file_type']?

Comment: Yes you send file by curl without type and in another POST field you send type. Then you change script on server to take file from $_FILE and type from $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I thought about it. In the issue:

**curl part:**

```
if ( !empty($_FILES) ){

        foreach ($_FILES as $param => $file) {

            if ( $file['tmp_name'] ){

                $post[$param]='@' . $file['tmp_name'];
                $post['_ftype']=$file['type'];
                $post['_ffilename']=$file['name'];
                $post['_ffileuploadname']=$param;
            }
        }
}
```

**server part:**

```
if ( !empty($_FILES) && isset($_POST['_ffileuploadname']) ){

    $name=$_POST['_ffileuploadname'];
    $_FILES[$name]['type']=$_POST['_ftype'];
    $_FILES[$name]['name']=$_POST['_ffilename'];
}
```